# Flutter pass data from one class to another(statefull widget)

Tags: flutter

How can i pass the data that i get from user via _textController and save it on a variable on the other class? I want to get the data that i get from the user and save it on a variable on the other class

```
 final _textController = TextEditingController();
  String userPost = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(375, 812),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              body: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                      Color.fromRGBO(95, 44, 130, 1),
                      Color.fromRGBO(73, 160, 157, 1),
                    ])),
                
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.sp),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _textController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'What s your name?',
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _textController.clear();
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.clear))),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.h,
                      ),
                      MaterialButton(
                        elevation: 0,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userPost = _textController.text;
                            _textController.clear();
                          });
                        },
```

and displayed here :

```
 showToast();
                        NotificationService().showNotification(
                          1,
                          'You can, ',
                          randomName!,
                        );
                      },
```

I don t know how to pass the data

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) StateProvider.

```
final valueProvider = StateProvider<String>(
  (ref) => "",
);
```

For using this `valueProvider` u must use ConsumerStatefulWidget instead of StatefulWidget

Editing `valueProvider`

```
ref.watch(valueProvider.state).state = _textController.text
```

Using `valueProvider` from another ConsumerStatefulWidget

```
final text = ref.watch(valueProvider.notifier).state
```

**NOTE**

I recommend you look [State Management in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) topic I think it is critical part of Flutter Development.

Answer (score 0):

u could simply call the showtoast() function in the onpressed() for any button and pass it the parameters which you want to use,

as

```
onpressed() 
{
showtoast('message to toast');
other code--
}
```

and change this

```
 showToast();
                        NotificationService().showNotification(
                          1,
                          'You can, ',
                          randomName!,
                        );
                      },
```

to

```
 showToast(String message);
                        NotificationService().showNotification(
                          1,
                          'You can, ',
                          message,
                        );
                      },
```